# помощь в разборе скрипта JS

Tags: javascript

всем привет!

подскажите, пожалуйста, по следующему примеру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**каким образом параметр функции `guess`(passwordGuess) принимает значение `tryGuess`(nope) ?**

как я размышляю?

`tryGuess` есть ссылка на функцию `makePassword`. Вызывая просто tryGuess мы передаем "secret" в параметр функции `makePassword`. это вроде понятно. но как так получается, что мы в tryGuess указали параметр "nope" и он оказался не в `makePassword`, а в `guess` ?

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

И если можно, скиньте хороший ресурс, где доступно объясняются функциональные выражения, колбэки, замыкания и тп

```
makePassword(password) {
  return function guess(passwordGuess) {
  return (passwordGuess === password);
  };
 }
var tryGuess = makePassword("secret");
console.log("Guessing 'nope': " + tryGuess("nope"));
console.log("Guessing 'secret': " + tryGuess("secret"));
```

Comment: tryGuess это не ссылка на функцию makePassword. В tryGuess хранится значение, которое вернула функция makePassword, а она вернула другую функцию, которая в свою очередь будет возвращать true каждый раз, когда ее вызовут с тем же аргументом, что и функцию makePassword

Comment: сложна, ничего не понял)

Comment: Вы столкнулись с так называемым замыканием. Поскольку для JavaScript это одна из ключевых особенностей, полезно будет разобраться в ней подробно, например, здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/closure

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить код в текстовом виде... Чтобы люди могли его копировать для ответа.

Comment: добавил код:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже два примера основанные на твоем коде которые наглядно показывают механику.

Пример #1:

```
function makePassword (password) {
    return  password
    }

var tryGuess = makePassword("secret")

console.log(`tryGuess is ${typeof(tryGuess)} = ${tryGuess}`)
//выводим тип tryGuess и ее значение
```

Пример #2:

```
function makePassword (password) {
    return  function guess(passwordGuess) {
        return (`${password} + ${passwordGuess}`)
    }
}

var tryGuess = makePassword("secret")

console.log(`tryGuess is ${typeof(tryGuess)} = ${tryGuess}`)
console.log(`tryGuess is ${typeof(tryGuess)} = ${tryGuess("nope")}`)
//выводим тип tryGuess и ее значение, после выводим еще раз с подставленным значением nope
```

Comment: короче я сначала не понял, а потом как не поняяяял(шутка)

Comment: короче не знаю, что на меня повлияло(видимо 12ч рабочий день), но в очередной раз перечитывая главу про замыкание, я решил еще раз отдебажить код.
и я понял, что сначала браузер считал переменную tryguess, где мы ему передали параметр "secret", где сохранил его в локальной переменной password. эта переменная по сути сохраняется в функции.

Comment: ну далее идет просто вызов через консоль tryGuess c еще одним параметром, который сохранеятся в guess

Comment: ну я понял, что ты хотел сказать) спасибо тебе